# populating content inside div into multiple vertical coumns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

I have which is populated with content. How can this content vertially align into multiple columns like it's on image.

Update:

```
<div result>
   <div ng-repeat="n in data| orderBy:'-Number'">
       {{ n }}
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: hard to tell looking at the image need to see some code

Comment: which is your markup? an ordered list?

Comment: qwuestion is updated.

Comment: you can try  `column-count` property

Comment: @maioman any example?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can help:

```js
var sec = document.body.getElementsByTagName("section")[0];
for (var i=1; i<=150;i++){
    var n = document.createTextNode(i);
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(n);
    sec.appendChild(li)
}
```

```css
li{list-style:none}
section{    
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3; 
    column-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
```

Comment: great, is it possible to set height for each column explicitly, like first column height to be auto, second 200px and third also 200px ?

Comment: no, If you want to divide in  columns defined by yourself the best solution might be pureJS and a basic CSS grid